# EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'touched' of null

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to use Reactive forms in my Angular2 application but I am running into an exception as below

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'touched' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'touched' of null

My sample code is as below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { Customer } from './customer';

@Component({
moduleId:module.id,
templateUrl: 'sign-up.reactiveForms.html'
})

export class SignupComponent  {

customer: Customer= new Customer();


customerForm : FormGroup; //it assosciate html element with this root model

ngOnInit() : void {


   this.customerForm=new FormGroup({

        firstName: new FormControl(),
         lastName: new FormControl(),
         email: new FormControl(),
         sendCatalog: new FormControl(true)

   });
}

save() {
    console.log(this.customerForm);
  }

}
```

sign-up.reactiveForms.html file is as below

```
            <!-- First Name input -->

            <div class="form-group"
                [ngClass]="{'has-error': (customerForm.get('firstName').touched ||customerForm.get('firstName').dirty) && !customerForm.get('firstName').valid }">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                       for="firstNameId">First Name</label>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="firstNameId" 
                           type="text" 
                           placeholder="First Name (required)" 
                           required 
                           minlength="3"
                           formControlName="firstName"
                             />
                    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(customerForm.get('firstName').touched || customerForm.get('firstName').dirty) && customerForm.get('firstName').errors">
                        <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('firstName').errors.required">
                            Please enter your first name.
                        </span>
                        <span *ngIf="customerForm.get('firstName').errors.minlength">
                            The first name must be longer than 3 characters.
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am trying to figure it out why touched property is null.

Comment: That message doesn't mean the touched property is null, it means customerForm doesn't have a firstName.

Comment: Tried your code, and I couldn't reproduce your issue, meaning it worked fine for me. As a wild guess, try and use safe navigation operator. At least that should take care of the null-error, but maybe then validation won't work (?). But try... e.g: `customerForm.get('firstName')?.touched`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and initialize your form controls, so that they won't be `null`:

```
this.customerForm=new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    email: new FormControl(''),
    sendCatalog: new FormControl(true)
});
```

Otherwise maybe using the safe navigation operator would remove the null error, by e.g:

```
customerForm.get('firstName')?.touched
```

But initializing the form controls alone should (hopefully) take care of this.